# Django - ValueError: ModelState.fields cannot refer to a model class - "tags.to" does. Use a string reference instead

Tags: python, django, django-1.9

I have this migration:

```
# encoding: utf8
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('main', '0013_post_tags'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='guidauser',
            name='avatar',
            field=models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=''),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
    ]
```

It works perfectly with Django 1.7.9. But now I have upgraded project to Django 1.9. And If I try to deploy it(locally), 'manage.py migrate' cause error:

[image]

But, it works with Django 1.8.8

models.py:

```
class GuidaUser(User):
    GENDER_MALE = 'male'
    GENDER_FEMALE = 'female'

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (GENDER_MALE, 'Чоловіча'),
        (GENDER_FEMALE, 'Жіноча'),
    )
    about_yourself = models.TextField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    contacts = models.ForeignKey(GuidaUserContacts, blank=True, null=True, related_name='contacts')
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=GENDER_MALE, blank=True, max_length=10)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    #work = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ip_register = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True, default=None)
    has_username = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = UserManager()
```

And It seems, that this error is related with previous migration(but Django apply it), so here it is:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('main', '0012_auto_20140721_1650'),
    ('taggit', '__first__'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='post',
        name='tags',
        field=taggit.managers.TaggableManager(to=taggit.models.Tag, through=taggit.models.TaggedItem, help_text='A comma-separated list of tags.', verbose_name='Tags'),
        preserve_default=True,
    ),
]
```

So, how to fix it?

Comment: I'm working with Django 1.8.x and 1.9 will pass soon. Would you put the piece of code involved _models.py_?

Comment: @JavierClavero I have edited question..

Comment: I have been watching carefully. In the repository Django, this error is indicated here, to see if it clears something or someone else can help. (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/migrations/state.py#L375)

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
field=taggit.managers.TaggableManager(to=taggit.models.Tag,
                                      through=taggit.models.TaggedItem,
                                      help_text='A comma-separated list of tags.',
                                      verbose_name='Tags')
```

With

```
field=taggit.managers.TaggableManager(to='taggit.models.Tag',
                                      through='taggit.models.TaggedItem',
                                      help_text='A comma-separated list of tags.',
                                      verbose_name='Tags')
```

The error is telling you that you cannot have classes inside fields, instead use the class name as a string.